# Python - Return list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to return a list of tuples in the below

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    t1 = [('a', 'string', 'a', 'string'), ('b', 'string', 'b', 'string')]

    print(t1)
    return t1
```

When I `print` the list or convert the list to `str` -> `print`, I get the below:

```
[('a', 'string', 'a', 'string'), ('b', 'string', 'b', 'string')]
```

When I `return` I get

```
[
  [
    "a",
    "string",
    "a",
    "string"
  ],
  [
    "b",
    "string",
    "b",
    "string"
  ]
]
```

My challenge is that I need to submit a list of tuples for an AWS Glue Job service:

```
ApplyMapping.apply(frame = datasource0, mappings = [("a", "string", "a", "string"), ("b", "string", "b", "string")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1")
```

But I pass (MY_LIST_PARAM) which is the output of the `return` command:

```
ApplyMapping.apply(frame = datasource0, mappings = MY_LIST_PARAM, transformation_ctx = "applymapping1")
```

However, I then get the following error:

```
TypeError: Mapping must be specified as a tuple. Got [
```

I can't hard code the values, as it is a single job which take the argument list and applies that in the job logic. Printing the List as a String doesn't help me (even though it looks correct) as I need a list of tuples in format `[(),()]` and not `[[],[]]`.

I am using Python 3.7. Also executing in AWS Lambda (but this should not make a difference)

Comment: I think it requires tuple of tuples. The error has a problem with the outer list, not the inner tuples. Because there is no way a list of list is returned

Comment: What is `MY_LIST_PARAM`? Something tells me your list of tuples is being serialized to JSON, then deserialized. As JSON only has one ordered sequence type (the array), both `list`s and `tuple`s are encoded as arrays, but then the JSON array is always decoded to a `list`; there's no way to tell what the original was.

Comment: `When I return I get` Cannot reproduce. As Eternal said - "there is no way a list of list is returned"

Comment: Try making it tuple of tuples

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Also executing in AWS Lambda (but this should not make a difference)

I expect it does. I'd guess the data is moved from lambda to glue (or whatever) as JSON[0], JSON doesn't have tuples so python converts tuples to JSON arrays, which become lists on the other side.

Convert the lists back to tuples on the receiver side if the API you're calling throws a fit when given lists. It's just a matter of running a list comprehension or `list(map(tuple, MY_LIST_PARAM))`.

[0] or some other format with similar capabilities / limitations I can't think of any serialisation format which would provide for Python's distinction between tuples and lists which is only a matter of mutability (and thus not really a concern to serialisation formats), they *might* have something like an "anoymous structure" or "anonymous record" but Python tuples would rarely get serialized to that, at least implicitly

Comment: Thanks a lot for this - it worked! On the receiver side, I converted the lists back to tuples and it worked perfectly.